# How to exit script within a submit() event in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms

My simple form validation scripts outputs a JS `alert()` if any field value doesn't have at least 3 characters. For some reason, after the `alert()` the page scrolls up to top instead of simply doing nothing. Why?

```
$('submit_button').submit(function() {
  $(this).find('input:not(input[type=submit])').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length < 3) {
      alert('Please fill all fields');
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 1):

If you want the browser to not complete the default action (for example - submit the form when you click on the `submit` button), you should use the `preventDefault` method on the current event:

```
$('submit_button').submit(function(e) {
    ...
    ...
    if ($(this).val().length < 3) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Please fill all fields');
        return false;
    }
```

> Note that I added the `e` variable (which will be the event of the submit) to the function in order to be able to prevent the default action there).

Comment: Worked! But why do I still need the return false?

Comment: The return false is not needed in order to prevent the submit, but it is needed for other actions you might have there (and if for example you don't want to complete other checking inside the `submit` function. It really depends on the rest of your code.